# how to know if the difference between test and train RMSE is significant to say its overfitted/under-fitted

Tags: regression, random-forest, overfitting, rms

I am trying to figure out if the model is overfitted/under-fitted based on RMSE values on test and train errors.

On the training data, the RMSE is 0.283

On the test data, the RMSE is 0.758

since `RMSE(test) > RMSE(train)`, I want to conclude that the model is overfitted but is this difference significant enough to conclude this?

It's a Random forest regression model and Y(dependent variable) values are in range(2-7).

Comment: One possibility is to modify the random forest model to be less likely to overfit, such as using fewer trees, smaller depth, etc.  Then see how that model does on the test data.

Comment: Thanks Glen for recommending hyper parameter tuning but my question is about overfitting conclusion based on test/train error difference. Can you please reply about that ?

Comment: There's no way to tell from just RMSE train/test values; it's problem specific.  That's why I suggested tuning the model to where it should overfit and underfit.  Then you'll have an idea of what the optimal test RMSE is.